# The reward video is no longer showing

Tags: android, video, sdk, ads

(and sorry for my English),

My application no longer displays advertisements, whether in test mode or downloaded from the Play Store. I've tried with different platforms (start.io, unity, approving), and I always get a blank screen, like the ad keeps loading or, in the case of start.io, it always returns onFailedToReceiveAd.

I modified the code several times, reimplemented the SDK, and the permissions, and updated gradle.build, nothing helps.
I would point out, however, that until three weeks ago, the advertisements were displayed correctly with start.io.

I contacted start.io, and they said they are working on my case, but it's been 4 days now. I admit I don't know what to do anymore, so I'm asking for your help, please.

Here's the code for an ad that used to display perfectly fine with start.io, but no longer works (it still returns onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad)). Thank you so much!

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.Ad;
import com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.StartAppAd;
import com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.StartAppSDK;
import com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.VideoListener;
import com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.adlisteners.AdEventListener;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

/*13/12/22*/

public class Pub1b extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StartAppSDK startAppAd = new StartAppSDK();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "xxxx_ap_id", false);
        StartAppSDK.setTestAdsEnabled(true);
        StartAppSDK.setUserConsent (this,
                            "pas",
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),                        
                            true);
    StartAppSDK.setUserConsent (this,  
                            "pas",
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),                        
                            false);
        final StartAppAd rewardedVideo = new StartAppAd(this);
        rewardedVideo.setVideoListener((VideoListener) () -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Pub1b.this, Ind1b.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
            finish();
        });
        rewardedVideo.loadAd(StartAppAd.AdMode.REWARDED_VIDEO, new AdEventListener() {

             @Override
            public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
                rewardedVideo.showAd();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
                Toast.makeText(Ub1b.this, getString(R.string.zjj), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Pub1b.this, Helpp1b.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, I notice some errors on your code,

Your code has 2 boolean values for user consent. This is likely incorrect.

```
StartAppSDK.setUserConsent (this,
                            "pas",
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),                        
                            true);
    StartAppSDK.setUserConsent (this,  
                            "pas",
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),                        
                            false);
```

your class `Pub1b` uses `StartAppSDK` but it assigns to `startAppAd` which is not being used anywhere (is that a complete code?) If not used you should remove that line if not required.

To debug your app you should do the ff:

**check your logcat**, see if there are warnings or errors that are related to your `StartAppSDK` this will narrow things down on why your ad isn't showing.

**Update SDK ver**, check your `build.gradle` and update yours to latest version. this might solve your problem.

**Double check your Ad Unit ID**, if this is incorrect it will not load your ads.

**check AndroidManifest.xml file,** make sure you have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Test on sample project or on multiple devices.** this will narrow down your issue.